# Compile Error When compile gRPC that `‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, grpc

I am trying to compile `grpc_python_plugin`. I downloaded the latest `grpc` package in Github. Following the instruction, I went into the `grpc` directory, and start to compile with

```
make grpc_python_plugin
```

, and get the following error:

```
wcf@wcf-OptiPlex-7060:~/resq/grpc$ make grpc_python_plugin
[C]       Compiling third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.c
cc1: error: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2972: recipe for target '/home/wcf/resq/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.o' failed
make: *** [/home/wcf/resq/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.o] Error 1
```

Since the `Makefile` for `grpc` is so giant, I cannot find any way to solve the problem. Could you share some idea on my problem? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your makefile seems to be invoking the C compiler instead of C++ compiler. Or you probably need `-std=c11` instead of `c++11`

Comment: You can have a glimpse at `grpc`'s Makefile, it has more than 20000 lines. It is no clear what to chance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that I install the `protobuf` outside the `grpc` git program. When I install `protobuf` in `grpc`'s `third_party`. All things go well.

Answer (score 0):

The way I made it work was deleting "-Werror" from CPPFLAGS in the Makefile. But yes, I also installed protobuf outside of grpc.